# Video background via CSS covers footer on Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background, html5-video

My company is using Wordpress; I have found some useful code for having a video act as a background and we are happy about how quickly it loads on our web browser. Unfortunately this background displays on top of the footer so the footer is no longer viewable. I have inserted the html code in two ways: 1. Used "raw html" field in Visual Composer, 2. Inserted html code via Wordpress text editor. As I mentioned the code works very well, but it covers the footer. 
Here is the location of the page: http://gathereducation.com/homepage-html-5-video/.

Here is the html, CSS, and JS:

HTML:

```
<video autoplay loop poster="/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/student_pov.jpg" id="bgvid">
<source src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/HomepageBannerNewClass.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/HomepageBannerNewClass.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

CSS:

```
video { display: block; }

video#bgvid {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
width: auto; height: auto; 
z-index: -100;
background: url(/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/student_pov.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
.content { background: url(http://gathereducation.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/student_pov.jpg) #000 no-repeat center center fixed; }
#bgvid { display: none; }
}
```

RAW JS:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
document.createElement('video');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I think I have an understanding of what is causing the problem, but I am unable to figure out the best way to have the footer display below the background - not underneath it.

Thanks!

Comment: Just add to you footer -> footer{ z-index:9999;}

Comment: Worked great, but I am missing my #footerbottom now. I tried doing z-index:9999, but it does not display. Anything thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Give .footerbottom{ position: relative}

Comment: Don´t forget that you should have z-index:9999 in the footerbottom and add position: relative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a z-index to your footer.

```
footer {
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Worked like a charm in Chrome.

Comment: you don´t need to copy... The same answer was already in the comment zone.

Comment: @Luis - I didn't copy. I knew the answer and posted it. I never saw the comment. I thought the point was to post solutions as answers.